# How to create AlertDialog with single choice checkbox in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

How to implement single choice with checkboxes in AlertDialog? I try to implement with *setSingleChoiceItems*, but it displays radio button. *setMultiChoiceItems* displays checkboxes but there user can check multiple items. I need to implement singleChoice with Checkboxes. I need yr help?

Comment: you have need to make it custom layout and add it on activity it will solve

Comment: How many checkboxes are you having in total?

Comment: I have only two checkboxes and i didn`t want to create custom layout

Comment: "it" does that because thats what radio buttons are meant for :) , you can change the background of the radio button to display it as a checkbox, customise it like [custom-android-checkbox-radiobutton](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/custom-android-checkbox-radiobutton/)

Comment: Radio button work on GroupRadiobutton so you have need to add code here GroupRadiobutton

Comment: if you want to do it only single check checkbox then you have need to do it .get boolean variable and assign values for that variable true make variable at check press make false then check that valu assigned value... it will solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically, with only two checkboxes, you can write a `switch` case or `if-else` loop with the `onCheckChangedListener` like;

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
if(isChecked){
switch(arg0.getId())
  {
    case R.id.cbOne:
         cbOne.setChecked(true);
         cbTwo.setChecked(false);
         break;
    case R.id.cbTwo:
         cbTwo.setChecked(true);
         cbOne.setChecked(false);
         break;

  }
}
```

And for both checkbox items you can set the listener as:

```
yourCb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.yourCb);
yourCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(yourListener);
```

If you customise the background, the default behaviour would also suit your requirement.. [custom-android-checkbox-radiobutton](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/custom-android-checkbox-radiobutton/)

Comment: How can i find checkbox item from alertdialog if i`m using setMultiChoiceItems ?

Comment: from the id of checkbox